# RSA Archer - Bulk Import Attachments

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

My client has a requirement for Bulk importing attachment files for Exisiting records in the Archer system., Since doing data import doesn't help them in importing attachments. I have come to understand that we can use Datafeed to do it. But i am confused on how to proceed. If anyone has any suggestions or Guides for this, it would be much appreciated.

i Made a data feed but not sure y but it doesn't work.
the transporter was file transporter but  i am still not able to import it to the system.Please Advice and a step by step guide to do it will also greatly help me

thanks

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In the CSV file for the attachment field would be the complete path to the file from the perspective of server(s) that are running the Archer Job service and whatever account the service is running as must have access to that path and file.  The path and filename cannot exceed 256 characters.

For example, \\server\path\filename.ext